# `let y = x` vs `let &y = &x`

Tags: rust, reference

What is the difference between the following [two assignments](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=beeca1245c040e9c602250ed0ba38e61)?

```rust
    let mut x = 1;
    let mut y = x; // (1)
    let &mut mut y = &mut x; // (2)
```

It appears they behave the same. Does #2 give you additional functionality not afforded by #1?

(the `mut` confuses here, but the point is the difference between no `&` on both sides, and `&` on both sides)

Answer (score 2):

(3) is equivalent to:

```rust
let mut y = *&mut x;
```

That is, create a reference and immediately dereference it. If `x`'s type is `Copy`, then (2) and (3) are equal: both create a copy (there are some esoteric differences about aliasing ((3) invalidates existing pointers to `x` but (2) does not), but usually they don't matter).

If `x` is not `Copy`, however, then (2) will work and move `x` into `y`, but (3) will not because you cannot move out of references.

Answer (score 0):

1. first one initializes a mutable variable. Ownership of `x` is established
2. second one creates a new mutable variable `y` and assigns the value of `x` to it. `x` and `y` are independent so any value change of one wont affect the other
3. third one's an error, it attempts to do multiple borrow of mutable variables

are you trying something like this?:
`let y_ref = &mut x;`

or [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7355890ffa89b3c44ac7124e1eb79453):

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 1;

    {
        let y = &mut x;

        println!("Before: y = {}", y);

        *y = 42; // Change the value through the reference
        
    }

    println!("After: x = {}", x);
}
```

the `&mut` is instead of being independent like in (2), it instead creates a reference and any changes will reflect on the referred variable

Comment: Re 3), the compiler doesn't think it's an error, and it is actually independent of `x`. Click on link to playground to confirm

Comment: in the playground after declaring `y` a mutable reference to `x` you assign it as `y = 3` so you're assigning 3 to `y` directly instead of pointing to the reference. it should've been something like `*y = 3`